# JDBC sink topic with multiple structs to postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to sink a few topics top a postgres database. However the topic schema defines a array at the top level and within it multiple structs. Automapping does not work and I cannot find any reference how to handle this. I need all structs because they are dependent types, the second struct references the first struct as a field.

Currently it breaks when hitting the 2nd struct stating `statusChangeEvent (struct) has no mapping to sql column type`. This because it is using auto.create to make a table (probably called ProcessStatus) then when hitting the second entry there is no column of course.

```
[
    {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "processStatus",
        "namespace": "company.some.process",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "code",
                "doc": "The code of the processStatus",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "doc": "The name of the processStatus",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "description",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "isCompleted",
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            {
                "name": "isSuccessfullyCompleted",
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "StatusChangeEvent",
        "namespace": "company.some.process",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "contNumber",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "processId",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "processVersion",
                "type": "int"
            },
            {
                "name": "extProcessId",
                "type": [
                    "null",
                    "string"
                ],
                "default": null
            },
            {
                "name": "fromStatus",
                "type": "process.status"
            },
            {
                "name": "toStatus",
                "doc": "The new status of the process",
                "type": "company.some.process.processStatus"
            },
            {
                "name": "changeDateTime",
                "type": "long",
                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
            },
            {
                "name": "isPublic",
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am not using ksql atm. Which connector settings are suited for this task? If there is a ksql alternative it would be nice to know but the current requirement is to use the JDBC connector.

I tried using flatten but it does not support struct fields that have a schema. Which seems kind of weird. Aren't schema's the whole selling point of connect with kafka? Or is it more of a constraint you have to work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Aren't schema's the whole selling point of connect with kafka?

Yes, but Postgres (or the JDBC Sink, in general) doesn't really support nested objects within columns. For that, you're better off with a document database, such as using Mongo Sink Connector.

> Which connector settings are suited for this task?

None, really, other than transforms. You could write your own if flatten doesn't work.

You could try pre-defining your table to use JSONB for the two status columns, however, that's more of a workaround.